# Serving a second application from a sub-path of another

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to serve two django projects from the same server using WSGI, but require that one run from example.com/ (let's call that app1) and the other from example.com/foo/ (app2).  I tried setting this up with separate daemon processes as described in Graham's comment [here](http://mediacore.com/blog/hosting-multiple-wsgi-applications-with-apache), but that appears not to work when one of the paths is a subdirectory of the other.  All requests for example.com/foo/... are still being handled by the app1.

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm looking for without needing to combine the two projects into one (which would be a difficult task)?

This is what I currently have in my site configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 \
    python-path=<path for app1's virtualenv>
WSGIDaemonProcess app2 \
    python-path=<path for app2's virtualenv>
WSGIScriptAlias / <path to app1's wsgi.py>
WSGIScriptAlias /foo/ <path to app2's wsgi.py>

<Location />
WSGIProcessGroup app1
</Location>

<Location /foo/>
WSGIProcessGroup app2
</Location>
```

Update:

I've tried using LocationMatch instead of Location to try to have every request to a path that doesn't start with /foo delegated to app1 and those that do to app2, but that doesn't work either for some reason.  Now, requests to /foo/... result in a 500 error with this line in the error log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=12032): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '<app1's wsgi.py>'.
```

Any ideas?

The bottom of the above has been changed to

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!foo.*)">
WSGIProcessGroup app1
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/foo.*">
WSGIProcessGroup app2
</LocationMatch>
```

Update 2:

After looking at the error log further, it looks like the requests to /foo/... are being handled by app1's wsgi.py file, but using the python path for app2, meaning that the correct WSGIProcessGroup directive is being applied.  Therefore, the problem appears to be a ScriptAlias collision.  Is it possible to have this alias be a regex as well to make sure /foo... is not matched to /?

Comment: That looks all right. You've triple checked for copy paste errors in your paths and restarted apache twice for good measure?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure everything's as it should be, but app1 is still taking precedence (in the configuration prior to my edit).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 \
    python-path=<path for app1's virtualenv>
WSGIDaemonProcess app2 \
    python-path=<path for app2's virtualenv>

WSGIScriptAlias /foo <path to app2's wsgi.py>
WSGIScriptAlias / <path to app1's wsgi.py>


WSGIProcessGroup app1

<Location /foo>
WSGIProcessGroup app2
</Location>
```

The order of the WSGIScriptAlias directives is important. The most deeply nested URL paths must come first.

This particular ordering issue is documented in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Comment: I thought I already tried this, but maybe I didn't restart apache or something.  Will try again.  Thanks!

Comment: It is also important to note that Graham removed the trailing slash from your /foo WSGIScriptAlias

Comment: The trailing slash is not relevant to the original problem. In general I would say not to have a trailing slash for a WSGI application mounted at a sub URL. This then allows the WSGI application handling it to decide if it wants to handle that URL, or whether it wants to force a trailing slash redirection. By having the trailing slash in the WSGIScriptAlias you take away that choice from the WSGI application.

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions turned out to be the solution.  WSGIScriptAliasMatch is able to match a specific regex for a path instead of just the beginning of the path, which caused a collision because, obviously, both paths begin with /.

For posterity, here's the final configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 \
    python-path=<path for app1's virtualenv>
WSGIDaemonProcess app2 \
    python-path=<path for app2's virtualenv>
WSGIScriptAliasMatch "^/(?!foo.*)" <path to app1's wsgi.py>
WSGIScriptAlias /foo <path to app2's wsgi.py>

<LocationMatch "^/(?!foo.*)">
WSGIProcessGroup app1
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/foo.*">
WSGIProcessGroup app2
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: The instant someone uses WSGIScriptAliasMatch it is a good indicator they don't understand what should be done. See my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but not the rudeness.

Comment: I really wanted to emphasise the point that WSGIScriptAliasMatch is really the wrong approach. The mod_wsgi documentation does not promote using WSGIScriptAliasMatch. There are unfortunately a few blog posts out there which do suggest using it even though one can nearly always do the same thing with simpler and more efficient WSGIScriptAlias. Any comment is not specifically directed at you, but for people who will come along later and read this so they think twice about doing it.

Comment: I tend to disagree with Graham Dumpleton's view. I think it's a very valid approach to use WSGIScriptAliasMatch because it allows to have each alias to be unambiguous my itself. WSGIScriptAlias may have a nicely readable ordering-based approach for clearing up the ambiguity, but it doesn't help if there are other directives that do not, for example ProxyPass directives colliding with the WSGIScriptAlias. So, Tiki's approach may extend better to more complex setups.